# Java Polymorphism error

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
class Parent{}

class Child extends Parent{

    public void display(){  
        System.out.println("Anything");  
    }  
}

Class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent obj = new Child();
        obj.display(); //error No function in Parent Class     
    }
}
```

Why We can't do this ?? obj have an object of Child type but still can't access display function ?

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
Parent obj = new Child();
```

You are creating a variable of type `Parent`. You are able to reference `new Child()` to obj is because `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`.

Since obj is declared as a `Parent`, it can only access properties and methods of `Parent`.

---

To enable it to access methods and properties of `Child`, you can cast it:

```
((Child)obj).display();
```

Casting it as `Child` is like telling Java to treat `obj` as `Child` from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that because the Parent class has no method display, so simple is that, if you want to call the method then you have to do something called casting

ie cast the  parent to a Child

```
((Child)obj).display();
```

PS: think about renaming the classes so they make more sense when formulating inheritance in simple human words...

Comment: Why are you recommending casting, as opposed to changing the type of `obj` to `Child`?

Comment: This was a question about polymorphism in general. Perhaps there could be other pieces of code where `obj = new Other();` where Other is also a subclass of Parent. or perhaps an array of `Parent obj[] = ...'  and the array is to be filled with various kinds of subclasses.  So there are legitimate cases where the cast is the right way to go.

Comment: I get it !! I was wrong as Object(Parent) and reference(Child) are different so Object can only access method of its own or overriding method !! Atleast legally it can't be done !!